# JSON::GeneratorError in a .js.erb file

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong..

I am attempting to catch a 401 unauthorized and inserting a div with a message before the submit button using

```
$(function() {
  return $("a").ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
      $(".submit").before(<%=j content_tag :div, "Does not compute" %> );
    }
  });
});
```

the name of the file is home.js.erb

even before the page loads I get

```
JSON::GeneratorError in Pages#home

Showing H:/project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed
  (in H:/project/app/assets/javascripts/home.js.erb)
```

line #6 refers to

```
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application.css", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

obviously something is wrong.. but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by removing the j..

which I don't understand... shouldn't j make it so I can put it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug of execjs that time:

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/129

Just update your execjs version to fix.